# Performing arithmetic on Characters in C

Tags: c, string, math, char, int

I am trying to write a program that adds, subtracts, multiplies, and divides a string of characters.  Where I'm at now with the program is figuring out how to split the input string into two strings, and then perform the appropriate +-/*.

The input should look like this abc+aaa

and the output for that should be abc + aaa = bcd

How do I convert character strings into integer strings?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

printf("This is a pseudo arithmetic program");

char input[10];
input[10] = '\0';
char first [9];
first[9] = '\0';
char last [9];
last[9] = '\0';

int i = 0; 
int b; 
int e;

while (input[0] != '0') {

if (input[0] == 0){
return -1;
}

printf("\nEnter a math problem in SOS format using only lowercase letters up to 9    characters");
printf("\nEx: abc+abc... type '0' to quit \n");
scanf("%s", input);

int x = 0;
x = strlen(input); 

    if (strchr(input, '+')){
    for (i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
         if (i == '+')
         strncpy(first, &input[0], i-1);
         i = 0;
    }
    for (i = x; i >= input[0]; i--) {
         if (i == '+')
         strncpy(last, &input[i], x);
         i = 0;    

    } 

     printf("%s", first);     
     printf(" + ");
     printf("%s", last);
     printf(" = %d", first + last);
    }
```

Comment: So what base are the input strings in? It looks like maybe base 26, with a=(the first non-zero value)? If so then what's the zero value? It's possible I'm just being foolish in not already knowing what SOS format is but Google seems not to help.

Comment: Just add the 2 character up, then subtract by character `'a'`.

Comment: I'm not to sure what you mean by base, but I believe a-z would be equal to 0-25, while A-Z is equal to 26-41.  So if the program was to do this problem a - a then the answer should be Z.  I don't think there is suppose to be a zero value at all.

Comment: nhahtdh could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be multiple problems with your code:

1. There is a array out of bounds happening for almost all the arrays:

   char input[10]; 
   input[10] = '\0';

In this if you want to initialize the last character with '\0' then it should be

```
input [9] = '\0'
```

Arrays indexes always start from 0.

1. It is not clear what is the use of below lines:

   while (input[0] != '0') {      if (input[0] == 0){   return -1;   }
2. When taking input for a string, why are prompting users to enter a 0 to end it?
3. strrchr returns the pointer from where the searched character begins. So, you can that itself to determine where the '+' symbol is and two split the strings instead of your while loop. See [strrchr man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strrchr/)
4. Also, your idea of adding characters is not clear. From your example, it appears you are considering a = 1, b = 2 etc. In such a case, if your code is case insensitive, then you can convert all your input to upper case and then do `(input[0] - 'A')+1` to convert your letters like a, b, c to 1, 2, 3 etc.

Hope these pointers help. Suggest you check your problem statement again and refactor your code accordingly.